# nvd3 Interactive Guideline hover not working properly

Tags: javascript, svg, graph, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using a cumulative line chart tracking multiple metrics over time. The interactive guideline on my chart is very unresponsive. The guideline will only show up when I hover over very small (~1px) areas on the chart. Below is the javascript for the chart creation:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.cumulativeLineChart().x(function(d) {
        return d[0];
    }).y(function(d) {
        return d[1];
    }).color(d3.scale.category10().range())
        .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
        .forceY([0]).showControls(false);

    var rotate = 0;
    if (datasets[0].values.length > 9) {
        rotate = -45;
    }

    chart.xAxis.showMaxMin(false).tickFormat(function(d) {
        if (inTimeFrame === 'day' || inTimeFrame === 'week')
            return d3.time.format('%b %e')(new Date(parseInt(d)));
        if (inTimeFrame === 'month')
            return d3.time.format('%b, %Y')(new Date(parseInt(d)));
        if (inTimeFrame === 'hour')
            return d3.time.format('%b %e %H:00')(new Date(parseInt(d)));

        return d3.time.format('%b %e %H:00 %Y')(new Date(parseInt(d)));
    }).tickValues(function() {
        var values = [], i = 0, numRows = datasets[0].values.length;
        var numLabels = 20, freqLabel = Math.floor(numRows / numLabels);
        var displayLabel = Math.floor(freqLabel / 2);

        $.each(datasets[0].values, function(a, b) {
            if (numRows > numLabels) {
                if (i === displayLabel) {
                    values.push(b[0]);
                    i++;
                } else if (i === freqLabel) {
                    i = 0;
                } else {
                    i++;
                }
            } else {
                if (i != 0) {
                    values.push(b[0]);
                }
                i++;
            }
        });
        return values;
    }).rotateLabels(rotate);

    chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.1%'));

    d3.select('#trend-svg').datum(datasets).transition().duration(500).call(chart);

    var state = chart.state();
    for (var i = 0; i < state.disabled.length; i++) {
        if (i > 2) {
            state.disabled[i] = true;
        }
    }

    chart.dispatch.changeState(state);
    chart.update();
    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    return chart;
});
```

Any suggestions on what the problem could be? I have another cumulative line chart elsewhere that works just fine, and I cant figure out how to get this one to behave properly.

Below is the code for the working graph:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.cumulativeLineChart()
        .x(function(d) { return d[0] })
        //adjusting, 100% is 1.00, not 100 as it is in the data
        .y(function(d) { return d[1] / 100 })
        .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
        .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
        .forceY([0,1])
        .showControls(false);
        var rotate = 0;
        if(allData[0].values.length > 9){
        rotate = -45;
        }
        chart.xAxis
        .showMaxMin(false)
        .tickFormat(function(d) {
        if(inTimeFrame === 'day' || inTimeFrame === 'week')
            return d3.time.format('%b %e')(new Date(d));
        if(inTimeFrame === 'month')
            return d3.time.format('%b, %Y')(new Date(d));
        if(inTimeFrame === 'hour')
            return d3.time.format('%b %e %H:00')(new Date(d));
        return d3.time.format('%b %e %H:00 %Y')(new Date(d));
        })
        .tickValues((function(){
            var values = [],
            i = 0,
            numRows = allData[0].values.length,
            numLabels = 20,
            freqLabel = Math.floor(numRows / numLabels),
            displayLabel = Math.floor(freqLabel / 2);
            $.each(allData[0].values, function(a,b){
                if(numRows > numLabels){
                        if(i === displayLabel){
                        values.push(b[0]);
                        i++;
                    }else if(i === freqLabel){
                        i = 0;
                    }else{
                        i++;
                    }
                }else{
                    if(i!=0){
                        values.push(b[0]);
                    }
                i++;
                }
            })
            return values;
        }))
        .rotateLabels(rotate);

        chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.1%'));

        d3.select('#responseAllGraph')
            .datum(allData)
            .transition().duration(500)
            .call(chart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

        return chart
    });
```

Comment: What is the difference between this code and the version that is working?  What CSS are you using?  Can you create a working example (on jsfiddle or similar) with some sample data?  The most likely reason for hover effects only happening on certain parts of the image is that other elements (possibly invisible) are on top and are catching the mouse events.

Comment: Edited to include code from the working graph. The CSS is the same between the two graphs.

Comment: I find that jsfiddle doesn't work so well with presenting nvd3 graphs, but here's one anyway. http://jsfiddle.net/aKrD5/

Comment: It seems like the tooltip will only appear when I hover over the tick lines for the y-axis.

Comment: You were getting a run-time error in your script "inTimeFrame is not defined", which was then exiting the script before the graph could complete.  When I commented out the tickFormat function that used that variable (and also changed the external resources on the fiddle to use the copies on nvd3.org), the rest of the graph works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/aKrD5/1/.  You might want to read up on the developer tools for your browser so that you know how to look for runtime error messages.

Comment: Ah, that was my mistake. The runtime error that is not actually present in my code. I updated your js fiddle to reflect this and it seems to be working. Sounds like the problem is with my version of the nvd3 stuff. I had made some modifications to fix some other problems in the past, but this gives me a place to look to try and fix the problem. Thanks. I'll post back when I get it all figure out.

Comment: Running those external files that you referenced in the jsfiddle would not work on my site. For whatever reason, I get a load of errors about illegal characters, d3 is undefined, and undefined is not a function. The d3 file has really strange characters like 'Ï€' that really shouldn't be there and is resulting in illegal character errors. I don't know how it is working on the js fiddle.

Comment: The d3 source files use unicode characters.  You may need to explicitly declare the charset when you import the script.  Regardless, you can still host your own versions of the library files; it wasn't working on jsfiddle because of cross-domain issues.  However, make sure the libraries are up to date -- the multi-value tooltip is a fairly recent modification to NVD3, so if you're working off old files that could be the problem.

Comment: That wouldn't make sense because I have another chart using the same javascript file, and the multi-value tooltip works fine there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% on this, but it seems that this issue came up more often when the graph's data was doing something funky. If you are having this issue, try auditing the data, and make sure your data makes perfect sense and you are using the appropriate graph type for what you are trying to do.

Comment: This also helped me fix an issue I had. I could only see the first and last datapoint when hovering and it turns out I had the timestamps in reverse order. Order really matters with NVD3 it turns out.